# I'm looking for a `PickOptional<T, K>` generic

Tags: typescript

Below I have an interface and I am picking sounds off of it, I'd like a generic that replaces pick / wraps it to 1) take any string key (currently type error on 'cluck' and 2) not put unknown properties, just simply leave it out.

```
interface Sounds {
    'meow': true
    "woof": false
}

type Sound = Pick<Sounds, 'woof' | 'cluck'>
//                                    /.\
//                                     |
// type Sound = {                  This throws 
//     woof: false;                    
//     cluck: unknown; <!--- I don't want this
// }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) with [`Extract<Type, Union>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter out the unwanted keys:

```
interface Sounds {
    meow: true;
    woof: false;
}

type PickOptional<T, U> = Pick<T, Extract<U, keyof T>>;  

type Sound = PickOptional<Sounds, 'woof' | 'cluck'>;

/* Evaluates to: 
type Sound = {
  woof: false;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to create an intermediate *Pick* type, using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

```
interface Sounds {
    'meow': true
    "woof": false
}

type PickIfExists<T, U> = Pick<T, U extends keyof T ? U : never>
type Sound = PickIfExists<Sounds, 'woof' | 'cluck'>

// type Sound = {
//   woof: false;
// }
```

Test it on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsCuIAmBnZAbwChkzkByAWwnQHcKAuZMKTCU8gIjvXRi7N4AGzwcAvsWJgAngAcUABWAIA1gEkYAUQAewPGDwAeACoAaZAFUAfMgC8yZWtMXLyCDsi4CqiDP7IJsgA-FbIzCAQAG7Q1tLyKBjYOPaOKhraegbGSd4WFLz8FMgAPpQIwphqFHHEQA).